# Threading in Rails - do params[] persist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, request, response

I am trying to spawn a thread in Rails. I am usually not comfortable using threads as I will need to have an in-depth knowledge of Rails' request/response cycle, yet I cannot avoid using one as my request times out.

In order to avoid the time out, I am using a thread within a request. My question here is simple. The thread that I've used accesses a params[] variable inside it. And things seem to work OK now. I want to know whether this is right? I'd be happy if someone can throw some light on using Threads in Rails during request/response cycle.

[Starting a bounty]

Comment: Where in the lifecycle do you spawn the thread?

Comment: @luke_randall : When a request is submitted, I spawn a thread inside the controller.

Comment: If you are firing off a thread to do some process that is causing your request to take too long you might want to look at something like `delayed_job` to run tasks asynchronously in the background.

Comment: Still more questions :) Is the thread to achieve concurrency in performing processing needed for the response, or is it for stuff that occurs outside of the request/response lifecycle? If the latter, I have to second Shadwells recommendation, but I'm assuming your use of threads is because it's the former...

Comment: @luke_randall: Well, I am more curious on what happens in the question I've asked (like whether the params[] variable will hold the value permanently) about instead of implementing either a delayed job or a background process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but only to a degree; the binding in which the thread was created will continue to persist. The params will still exist only if no one (including Rails) goes out of their way to modify or delete the params hash. Instead, they rely on the garbage collector to clean up these objects. Since the thread has access to the current context (called the "binding" in Ruby) when it was created, all the variables that can be reached from that scope (effectively the entire state when the thread was created) cannot be deleted by the garbage collector. However, as executing continues in the main thread, the values of the variables in that context can be changed by the main thread, or even by the thread you created, if it can access it. This is the benefit--and the downfall--of threads: they share memory with everything else.

You can emulate a very similar environment to Rails to test your problem, using a function as such: http://gist.github.com/637719. As you can see, the code still prints 5.

However, this is not the correct way to do this. The better way to pass data to a thread is to pass it to `Thread.new`, like so:

```
# always dup objects when passing into a thread, else you really
# haven't done yourself any good-it would still be the same memory
Thread.new(params.dup) do |params|
  puts params[:foo]
end
```

This way, you can be sure than any modifications to params will not affect your thread. The best practice is to *only* use data you pass to your thread in this way, or things that the thread itself created. Relying on the state of the program outside the thread is dangerous.

So as you can see, there are good reasons that this is not recommended. Multithreaded programming is **hard**, even in Ruby, and *especially* when you're dealing with as many libraries and dependencies as are used in Rails. In fact, Ruby seems to make it deceptively easy, but it's basically a trap. The bugs you will encounter are very subtle; they will happen "randomly" and be very hard to debug. This is why things like Resque, Delayed Job, and other background processing libraries are used so widely and recommended for Rails apps, and I would recommend the same.

Answer (score 1):

The question is more does rails keep the request open whilst the thread is running than does it persist the value.

It won't persist the value as soon as the request ends and I also wouldn't recommend holding the request open unless there is a real need. As other users have said some stuff is just better in a delayed job.

Having said that we used threading a couple of times to query multiple sources concurrently and actually reduce the response time of an app (that was only for admins so didn't need to have fast response times) and if memory serves correctly the thread can keep the request open if you call join at the end and wait for each thread to finish before continuing.